# Spring Kafka After commit listener

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I'm trying to write abstract code which should track offset changes and execute some actions after message processing. The thing is I don't want to change code of existing listeners too much.

Found some information about interceptors and AcknowledgingMessageListener - [Message Listener Containers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/receiving-messages/message-listener-container.html#page-title).

Interceptors are not really my case as need to execute action after and not before. AcknowledgingMessageListener - don't want/need to commit offsets manually.

[The event list](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/events.html) doesn't have one for me either.

Is there any elegant way to trigger some action after commit or message processing at least?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: According to the documentation (you linked to yourself) -> *Starting with version 2.7, it has additional methods which are called after the listener exits*, so there are methods to execute after listener execution.

Comment: I saw methods related to the lifecycle of listeners but not to records. @M.Deinum could you please highlight the methods you've mentioned?

Comment: The [`RecordInterceptor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/RecordInterceptor.html) clearly has methods for this (which are also mentioned in the documentation you linked yourself, you did read it didn't you?!). The [`BatchInterceptor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/BatchInterceptor.html) has similair methods, depending on if you commit per message or batch.

Comment: @M.Deinum did you read my question? I need to "trigger some action after commit". and documentation states "An interceptor for ConsumerRecord invoked by the listener container before and after invoking the listener.". Where do you see here after commit? did you read the doc?

Comment: After listener is after commit at least it should. How are you driving transactions in the firstplace? Add some code configuration to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, using a `RecordInterceptor` is the right strategy here. It gives options to capture successful listener exits and failures and a method to invoke after both successful and failure exits from the listener. Here is an example to intercept successful listener exits.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So77918542Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So77918542Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ConsumerFactory<String, String> kafkaConsumerFactory,
            RecordInterceptor<String, String> recordInterceptor) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(kafkaConsumerFactory);
        factory.setRecordInterceptor(recordInterceptor);
        return factory;
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so59256214.id", topics = "so77918542.topic")
    void listen(ConsumerRecord<String, String> in) {
        System.out.println("From KafkaListener: " + in);
    }

    @Bean
    public RecordInterceptor<String, String> recordInterceptor() {
        return new CompositeRecordInterceptor<>() {

            @Override
            public void success(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record, Consumer<String, String> consumer) {
                System.out.println("Listener exited: " + record);
            }

        };
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, Object> template) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("so77918542.topic", "my-data");
        };
    }

}
```

When running this application, I see the following in the output:

```
From KafkaListener: ConsumerRecord(topic = so77918542.topic, partition = 0, leaderEpoch = 0, offset = 3, CreateTime = 1706822418988, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 7, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = my-data)
Listener exited: ConsumerRecord(topic = so77918542.topic, partition = 0, leaderEpoch = 0, offset = 3, CreateTime = 1706822418988, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 7, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = my-data)
```

If you enable `asyncCommit`, you can register an `OffsetCommitCallback` on the container properties to listen for successful offset async committing. Here is an example:

```
@Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ConsumerFactory<String, String> kafkaConsumerFactory,
            RecordInterceptor<String, String> recordInterceptor) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(kafkaConsumerFactory);
        factory.setRecordInterceptor(recordInterceptor);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommits(false);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setCommitCallback((map, e) -> System.out.println("After async commit: " + map));
        return factory;
    }
```

When running with this, I see the following in the output:

```
From KafkaListener: ConsumerRecord(topic = so77918542.topic, partition = 0, leaderEpoch = 0, offset = 6, CreateTime = 1706899073272, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 7, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = my-data)
Listener exited: ConsumerRecord(topic = so77918542.topic, partition = 0, leaderEpoch = 0, offset = 6, CreateTime = 1706899073272, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 7, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = my-data)
After async commit: {so77918542.topic-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=7, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}}
```

Comment: but there are no guarantees that offset was or will be successfully committed in case of async commit.

Comment: I updated the answer with the async offset commit scenario.

Comment: thank you. so it's impossible to handle both sync and async cases with one type of handler/callback/interceptor?

Comment: That is correct. Commit callback is for async commits only.